# where do the trailing commas come from (perl)

Tags: csv, perl, parsing, text-files

Here is a perl script that takes a tab delimited output file and outputs three different text files, also tab delimited. Another user on SO helped me correct a mistake that created extra white-space at the end of each line in the output files. However, I wish to instead to output comma delimited text. When I substitute `print $Afile join( ",", @ADD) , "\n";` instead of  `print $Afile join( "\t", @ADD) , "\n";` I get two trailing commas at the end of each line in the output files. Where are these coming from?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

die "usage: [ imputed genotype.file ]\n" unless @ARGV == 1;

open my $Afile, ">$imputed" . "_ADD.txt" or die $!;
open my $Dfile, ">$imputed" . "_DOM.txt" or die $!;
open my $Ifile, ">$imputed" . "_IMP.txt" or die $!;

<>; #skip header
while(<>){ 
  chomp;
  my @entries = split( '\t', $_ );

  my @ADD = ();
  my @DOM = ();
  my @IMP = ();

  push( @ADD, $entries[ 0 ], $entries[ 1 ], $entries[ 2 ]);
  push( @DOM, $entries[ 0 ], $entries[ 1 ], $entries[ 2 ]);
  push( @IMP, $entries[ 0 ], $entries[ 1 ], $entries[ 2 ]);

  for ( my $i = 3; $i < scalar @entries - 1 ; $i+=3 ) { ### for each entry per line
      push( @ADD, $entries[ $i ] );
      push( @DOM, $entries[ $i + 1 ] );

  $entries[ $i + 2 ] =~ s/^NA$//; 

      push( @IMP, $entries[ $i + 2 ] );
  }

  print $Afile join( "\t", @ADD) , "\n"; 
  print $Dfile join( "\t", @DOM) , "\n"; 
  print $Ifile join( "\t", @IMP) , "\n"; 

} ### for loop   

close $Afile;
close $Dfile;
close $Ifile;
```

Comment: Change line 13 for: `my @entries = split(/\s+/);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since tabs are white space characters you do not see them with your current version but you already have trailing tabs. They are due to null elements in your arrays. You can filter them with grep though:

```
print $Afile join( ",", grep { $_ } @ADD) , "\n";
```

Comment: hi, I don't understand "null elements in [my] arrays." Where do these come from? Also, why are the trailing tabs not actually visible in the current version that outputs tab delimited text?

Comment: I don't know your input files, but by null elements I mean undefined array elements or elements that are empty strings

Comment: Perhaps you have some empty columns in your input

Comment: hi, my input file I  "cleaned" in excel by deleting/clearing the empty cells at the ends of the lines, and I checked in VIM to make sure there were no trailing tabs. As coded above, the script produces perfect output, that is, with no trailing tabs. Switching to commas instead of \t creates hanging commas, two per line. Does that make sense? thanks!

Comment: so, in VIM the file looks OK, there are no extra commas when I used your fix. However, the file does not open in excel so that each entry is in a separate cell. Everything in a line is bunched together.

Comment: when opening it in excel make sure you are using commas as delimeters

Comment: hi perlreal, excel doesn't ask what kind of separators i'd like, that window never pops up. excel just proceeds to open the file and cram everything into a cell. However, I then removed the .csv extension from my script where the files are opened (I replaced the .txt). Excel still doesn't ask me what kind of separators I would like, but it does fill in the cell correctly. It is like my attempt to place commas into my files is failing, and that excel is separating on white-space or something. When I open output in VIM, there are no commas. Can you see a mistake in the script?

Comment: look at this link: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-convert-delimited-text-files-into-excel-spreadsheets/, it may be of help

Comment: thanks for that link. on the otherhand, I still have a problem in that my code isn't putting in the commas for me when I replace `print $Afile join( "\t", @ADD) , "\n"; ` with `print $Afile join( ",", @ADD) , "\n";` , for example. Do you see why?

Comment: To ensure that split is done on *any one or more whitespace*, you could use `my @entries = split(/\s+/)` at line 13. ( **Nota:** `$_` is implicit variable when not specified, so `split(/\s+/)` is same as `split(/\s+/,$_)` )

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much by definition, `join` isn't going to introduce a trailing comma; it builds a string by inserting commas *between* elements of an array. But the elements of the array aren't necessarily what you think they are. Consider what happens when the snippet you supply gets a row like:

```
A,B,C,D,E,NA
```

The line `$entries[$i+2] =~ s/^NA$//;` means that `@IMP` will look like `('A', 'B', 'C', '')`, which will mean that `join(",", @IMP)` will be `"A,B,C,,"` and there's your trailing comma.

It's also possible that your input isn't all well formed. A line like `A,B,C,D` will leave `undef` values on a couple of your arrays, but `strict` and `warnings` mean that you would be seeing a bunch of errors in that case.

Comment: Hi @Piers Cawley, Yes I do get errors. I see "Use of uninitialized value $IMP[1] in join or string at parsing_4_for_csv.pl line 36, <> line 1135." for example. Just reams of these after running the script. However, the "extra comma" you are accounting for is not actually an extra, since I want to replace NAs with an empty space. So that comma at the end is OK. However, I would like to ask how can A line like `A,B,C,`D will leave `undef` values on a couple of your arrays? How does that happen?

Comment: Given `A,B,C,D`, you'll end up with an `@entries` array with four elements in it, but the first time through the loop, you'll be trying to read `$entries[4]` and `$entries[5]`, which don't exist, so you get `undef` back and bingo, there's your warnings.

In general, it's a good idea to pay attention when the interpreter spits out warnings and it's an even better idea to _mention_ that fact when you ask a question.